# How to implement field level Index time boost via DIH?

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to implement index time boost via DIH. but I want to boost at field level rather than document level. Ex:

Consider there are 2 fields in a document: LastUpdatedBy, fullName. After indexing both the fields, I am copying the data from both the field in to a default search field. Now when search happens on default search field I want fullNameto get more priority than LastUpdatedBy even though both might have the search keyword.

Note: I have tried dismax handler before for runtime boosting, want to try index time boosing using DIH.

Thanks!!!

Thanks, 
BB 
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding [Special Commands](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Special_Commands) to the DIH you can boost documents. But at that time field boosting for DIH is not implemented.

You can check the latest source code [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/contrib/dataimporthandler/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/DocBuilder.java).